# CLLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion crashes on ios 8.4

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon, estimote

I discovered that `startMonitoringForRegion` crashes on only iOS 8.4 giving me this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: major)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2af4a49f 0x38744c8b 0x2ae67c63 0x3c3bbd 0x380d6b 0x17fcd8 0x19f170 0xebe9db 0xebe9c7 0xec23ed 0x2af103b1 0x2af0eab1 0x2ae5c3c1 0x2ae5c1d3 0x3225a0a9 0x2e46a7b1 0x2ad734 0x38cc4aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The think is that `CLBeaconRegion` major value can be nil. So I don't know what is going on.

Here is the code:

```
if let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext{
    var dataFetch = DataFetcher()
    dataFetch.fetchBeacons(context, completion: { (success) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            var beacons = Beacon.getAllBeacons(context)
            if let uuid = beacons.first?.uuid {
                var region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: uuid), identifier: "iBeacon")
                region.notifyOnEntry = true
                region.notifyOnExit = true
                if self.isBluetoothOn {
                    self.manager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it is the `self.manager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)` line of code that is causing  the shown Exception?  I suspect it may be something else.  Try setting a breakpoint on that line and stepping over it to verify that is indeed what is causing it.

Comment: Try setting an exception breakpoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 1):

the error is

> setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: major)

This is more likely an NSDictionary error. And as it says, you are setting an object as nil. check once in your `major` key object is nil or not anywhere in your `viewcontroller`

Comment: major value is optional. Its nil here but in other ios versions it doesnot crash.

Comment: may be iOS is fixed this is issue in after iOS 9  that the reason is not worked in your older xcode, check once , if it is nil or not , it is easy to access

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely an NSDictionary error. And as it says, you are setting an object as nil.

You can find actual cause for it by adding "Exception" breakpoint. It will automatically stops your application and point to code location where you are getting this error. For more help I am attaching images showing how to add exception breakpoint.

1)Go to breakpoint section of project navigator.

[image]

2)Then click on '+' icon on bottom left corner and select add exception breakpoint.

[image]

3)After adding breakpoint, re run your code, you will find where it is causing problem.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After many days searching , i found out that i had a third party framework messing with this. The framework is the sdk of taplytics , a push notifications service.

Thanks you guys for the help.